# What are "universal minimum" standards of tznius for halachic purposes?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue, torah-service, parts-of-the-body, tznius-modesty

What are the minimum standards of tznius for halachic purposes? By "halachic purposes" I mean Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 75, which forbids praying in the presence of ervah. I am raising the question in light of the discussion begun [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7725/how-does-an-outsider-know-how-to-dress-for-a-particular-orthodox-community), which deals with the fact that different communities can have vastly different standards of tznius.

Which body parts must absolutely be covered from a halachic perspective? If a woman shows, for example, her collarbones, elbows, or hair because her minhag permits it, is she invalidating (or worse) the prayers of those around her with a different minhag? And, tangentially, what would those others be obliged to do in such a situation? I am thinking of kiruv settings, among others.

Comment: Also interested in the extent to which a mechitza makes a difference from a halachic standpoint. I can ask the mechitza part as a separate question if others recommend it.

Comment: Probably better separate, yeah. IMO. (+1 on this one, incidentally.)

Comment: this is a matter of dispute among various rishonim, achronim and contemporary authorities.

Comment: @ه ه, since you are awarding a bounty, please comment on the answers and tell me which you like. (Or can one award a bounty to any answer, even if it isn't the accepted one? Sorry for my lack of Stackexchange technical knowledge...)

Comment: The halacha differs significantly if you are asking about the requirements for the woman herself (e.g., if she is praying alone) or in the presence of other women or other men. Are you talking about all three situations?

Comment: @SAH He can give the bounty to anyone independent of whom you accept.

Comment: @TorasEMES613, I am talking about the latter, specifically when the "other people" have different minhags. If she were alone she would follow her own minhag.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7725/how-does-an-outsider-know-how-to-dress-for-a-particular-orthodox-community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halachic requirements to allow men to pray in the presence of women differ somewhat from modesty requirements incumbent upon the woman when in the presence of others. Appropriate dress (according to the lenient opinions) when praying in the presence of others, is as follows:

The halacha is that "tefach b'isha ervah" - a tefach (about 3.5 inches) uncovered on certain parts of a woman's body is ervah - nakedness. (B'rachos (24a) in the name of Rabbi Yitzchak). The arm must be covered at least to the elbow and the leg must be covered at least to the knee.

If a married woman is dressed with uncovered hair where uncovered hair is common among married women (though in violation of halacha), according to the Aruch HaShulchan (Orach Chaim: 75; 7) who rules leniently, he writes that it is permitted to pray in the presence of these women (quoting the Mordechai who quotes the Raviah).

Rabbi Getsel Ellinson (Woman and the Mitzvot: Volume 2) - Pg. 186, note 37, writes that it is probably okay to pray as long as there's less than a tefach uncovered above the elbows and knee. However, it is certainly absolutely forbidden to pray in the presence of a woman whose skirt does not cover past the knees when she is sitting down, because the skirt will not cover ervah.

Comment: I thought sephardic minhag allowed most of the upper arm to be uncovered?

Comment: This answer could really be improved by citing more sources (eg. about arm covering (the gemara you cite does not say zeroa b'isha erva)) and also dealing with other areas of the body (eg. neckline).

Comment: Can you cite me any Rishon at all who indicates that there is any objective standard of Tzniut (aside from Makom HaErvah)? I agree they all cite their standards. Do any of them at all indicate that if the custom were to change, the Halacha wouldn't?

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you looking for a Rishon that defines "Zero'a" and "Shok" (for example, while using language such as "everyone agrees that such is the definition"). Why would one think that these standards mentioned in the gemara are subjective (based on societal "norms") rather than objective? It's clear from the gemara that this is what "ervah" is, rather than something relevant to a given time period (for example).

Comment: @TorasEMES613 I said above "I agree they all cite their standards. Do any of them at all indicate that if the custom were to change, the Halacha wouldn't?" Re Zeroa: Dat Yehudit is defined by most (all?) Rishonim to be a Minhag, as you know. No indication it can't change. Re Shok: If the gemara meant to tell you it was objective Ervah, why don't Rishonim use that to answer why it says Shok in addition to Tefach (cf. [Beit Yosef OC 75](http://bit.ly/XRb5a9))? That would be a pretty obvious answer to a pretty strong question. The Rambam and Shulchan Arukh do not define any objective Ervah (cont)

Comment: locations (even Shok!). They just say "whatever location is usually covered". Sounds like they mean it literally, no? All kinds of Rishonim make up rules out of nowhere about Kol HaRagil Bo and Sear MiChutz LTzamata. Did they have special Mesora about these cases, or did they think everything was subjective? Why too doesnt anyone discuss the depth of a forbidden "plunging neckline" till 100 years ago? Was it that whatever is normal is ok or that the collarbone was an unwritten tradition for 1500 years since Rav Ashi? I think I have enough basis to ask for an early explicit source on the matter

Comment: @DoubleAA Here's a source - the Bach (1561/62-1640) an early Acharon who wrote about 400 years ago (Siman 75, S"K 2) http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x187: ונראה דנקט שוק דאפילו פחות מטפח נמי חשוב ערוה וכדנפקא לן (כ״ד
 ע״א) מקרא (ישעיה מ״ז ב) גלי שוק עברי נהרות וכתיב (שם ג) תגל ערותך
 דמשמע כל שוק הוי ערוה אפילו פחות מטפח...מה שאין כן שוק שלה
 אי לאו דגלי לן קרא דערוה היא, וכן קול ושער הוה אמינא דאין לחוש
 להן אפילו באשת איש, אי לאו דכתיב קרא (שיר השירים ב׳ י״ד) כי קולך ערב,
 ושערך כעדר העזים (שם ל׳ אי) דמדמשבח לה קרא בגוייהו שמע מינה תאוה הוא, והכי מוכח להדיא ממה שכתב רש״י וז״ל שוק

Comment: @DoubleAA While I presented the source in Hebrew for your benefit, just to paraphrase for others. The Bach (Rabbi Yoel Sirkis - known by the acronym of his work "Bayis Chadash" - Ba"Ch), quotes verses from the Book of Yeshyahu and Shir HaShirim, with respect to the Shok, a (married) woman's hair and voice (when singing) to demonstrate clearly that the places of Ervah are objective (objective Ervah does exist). I'd recommend checking out the source in full as I reference the link above. Thank you for your question and efforts to arrive at a source. I'm happy to have helped demonstrate otherwise

Comment: @TorasEMES613 That is my best source to offer too (though it still isn't a Rishon) (my second best is a line in the (forged) Eshkol). However, it's not clear the Bach stands by his Chiddush of Pachot MiTefach by the end of the paragraph (which you didn't finish quoting), and most everyone rejects him anyway. See, for example, the Arukh HaShulchan who says "ותמוה לפרש כן, דאם כן לא הוה ליה לסתום זה." If the Bach really is claiming some sort of objective Ervah, the Arukh Hashulchan thinks he is the first person to do so ever, and therefore rejects him.

Comment: Re your second comment: the Gemara quotes those verses. He just quotes the Gemara. They dont show by themselves that objective Ervah exists. The verses of Kol and Sear just show that Kol and Sear, when not a public form of them, are Ervah too _even though_ they are not strictly body parts. Hair that you are used to and voices that you are used to are not Ervah, dependent on the locale. That's how Rishonim know that unmarried women's hair and speaking voices are ok: because it's usually uncovered. Unmarried women's pubic hair is accordingly forbidden, but married women's eyebrows are ok. (cont)

Comment: (cont) The verse of Shok teaches that even though for a man the calf is uncovered, for a woman it is covered and problematic (at least, that's what all Rishonim who comment that I am aware of say).

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for pointing that out. The Ba"Ch quotes the Gemara and is even more explicit - when he notes one might think that there is no issue with hair (and some of the other Ervah) and then notes that these pesukim clearly demonstrate otherwise - that there is an objective source.

Comment: @TorasEMES613 It is an objective source that hair _can be_ Ervah. Not _which_ hair is Ervah. As I said above, pubic hair would likely be Ervah nowadays and eyebrows not (both for both married and unmarried women). If it weren't for the Pasuk I would think even pubic hair is not Ervah as it's not Body. (When I say pubic hair is Ervah, I mean that if 1 tefach of pubic hair was sticking out of her clothing while all the flesh was covered, it would still be prohibited to recite Shema there. I realize it's not a common case, but it is discussed in the Gemara there a few lines earlier regarding men)

Comment: (The full set of comments has been [archived in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/16789/2014/8/28)).

Answer (score 2):

In [Rabbi Marc Angel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_D._Angel)'s essay entitled [*A Modesty Proposal: Rethinking Tseniut*](http://www.jewishideas.org/marc-d-angel/modesty-proposal-rethinking-tseniut), he writes that all the laws of tznius are "inferred from the mandate to be holy—to separate ourselves from sin, including sin of a sexual nature."  (Rashi says on the pasuk *Kedoshim Tihyu* that holiness means separation from forbidden sexual relationships.)

R' Angel goes on to discuss more of the philosophy of tseniut, as well as halakhic technicalities that should be taken into consideration.

### Halacha lema'aseh:

Look about 2/3 or 3/4 down the page at the sections called "Confronting Reality" and "Tseniut Today" - that is where one can find the halakha lema'aseh.  He writes many things including (quote):

> 1. Neither men nor women should dress, speak, or act in a licentious manner that will arouse the sexual attention of others. It is a
>      violation of tseniut to wear skimpy, overly tight, or other clothing
>      that is designed to highlight one’s sexuality.
> 2. It is proper for men and women to dress nicely, neatly, and modestly. It is fine to dress fashionably, as long as those fashions
>      do not violate the philosophy of tseniut.
> 3. In our society, it is normal for upstanding and proper women to wear pants/pants suits; short sleeved dresses/blouses; clothes with
>      colorful designs. Wearing these things is not a violation of tseniut,
>      as long as these items are not fashioned in such a way as to highlight
>      one’s sexuality.
> 4. Married women need not cover their hair, as long as their hair is maintained in a modest style. The wearing of wigs does not constitute
>      a proper hair-covering for those married women who wish to cover their
>      hair. Rather, such women should wear hats or other head coverings that
>      actually cover their hair.
> 5. Men and women may sing in the presence of those of the other gender, as long as the songs are of a religious nature, or of a
>      general cultural nature (e.g. opera, folk songs, lullabies). People
>      should neither sing nor listen to songs that have vulgar language or
>      erotic content that will lead to improper thoughts or behavior.
> 6. If a person dresses, speaks, and acts in a proper, dignified manner, it is not his/her responsibility if others are sexually
>      aroused by him/her. That is their problem. It is their responsibility
>      to control their thoughts and emotions, and/or to remove themselves
>      from situations that they find to be sexually provocative.
> 7. Normal interactions between men and women are a feature of our societies. Women may serve in positions of authority over men, just as
>      men may serve in positions of authority over women. The key point is
>      this: holiness and tseniut should characterize all contexts where men
>      and women mingle and work together. Co-ed youth groups and schools are
>      permitted, but must be maintained with high standards of tseniut.

Finally, he concludes...

### Conclusion:

> Rabbi Avraham Shammah, who teaches at the Herzog Teachers’ College in
>   Israel, stated: “Women and men should behave in a manner that reflects
>   great respect for one another; they should not consider one another in
>   a crude manner such as sexual objects; they should not dress
>   provocatively, nor should their body language be provocative….” This
>   is a fine formulation of the guidelines of tseniut. It makes little
>   sense to pretend that our living conditions today are identical to
>   those of antiquity and the middle ages. Women’s roles in society have
>   changed radically. The interrelationships of men and women today are
>   far more common and far more frequent than in former times. Fashions
>   have changed dramatically. Definitions of brazenness and immodesty are
>   far different today than they were in olden days. Recognizing these
>   changes is essential to formulating a proper application of tseniut
>   rules. It must also be recognized, though, that modern-day fashions
>   often reflect very non-tseniut standards. Clothing that is designed to
>   be sexually provocative—low cut in front or back, dresses or skirts
>   above knee-length, clothing that is too tight, men’s pants that are
>   worn below the belt line, and so forth—are clearly in violation of the
>   philosophy and rules of tseniut. Our goal as thinking halakhic Jews is
>   to be clear on our responsibility to be holy, and to treat ourselves
>   and others as fellow human beings—not as sexual objects. When we live
>   as tseniut human beings, we enhance our own dignity and the dignity we
>   show to others. This is not an inconsiderable accomplishment.

Comment: What are the halachic sources for what Rabbis Angel and Shammah write? When providing a halachic response, it is imperative to include halachic responsa that is based in halacha. If the above is truly "Halacha l'ma'aseh", including statements such as a married woman's hair not being considered ervah and that a woman singing (religious songs) in front of men is not forbidden to listen to on account of kol isha, where is the halachic basis? These statements seem to be revolutionary and certainly require halachic sources (simply quoting these rabbis is not considered bringing a halachic source).

Comment: @TorasEMES613 AdamMosheh provided a link to an article which has sources at the bottom to many other articles as well. It is not his obligation to quote every source along the way. He gave you a way to get to the halachik responsa and the literature that this Rabbi based his rule on. Tzei Ulmad!

Comment: @DoubleAA I saw that article before I responded. With respect to married women not having to cover their hair, kol isha, and some of the other points, the article takes positions that are non-normative and outside of mainstream p'sak. In particular, the ruling permitting kol isha in general was derived from a quasi-Orthodox source, and that position is halachicly unacceptable. Also, the answer did not directly address the question, which was asking about tznius in the context of tefillah.

Comment: @TorasEMES613 I was not defending this post's status as an answer. Nor am I agreeing with the conclusions stated within. But you complained that he did not cite appropriate source material; I beg to differ. Those articles are full of traditional sources and arguments. If you'd like to take issue with them (without even citing your own sources), don't take it out on the messenger. Feel free to [start a new discussion](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @TorasEMES613 - Regarding *kol isha*: DoubleAA is correct; more than sufficient mekorot exist here.  R' Angel mentioned [this article](http://www.jewishideas.org/articles/new-hearing-kol-ishah), entitled *A New Hearing for Kol Ishah*, in a footnote of his *Rethinking Tseniut* essay (linked to in my answer above).  I highly suggest that you read it diligently.  You should also examine both the *Works Cited* and the *Endnotes* sections there.  I don't know how you arrived at the conclusion that the p'sak is "quasi"-halachic.

Comment: @TorasEMES613 - The question mentioned  about *tefillah*, but the question was asking not only about prayer, but also *kiruv* settings and which body parts must be covered from a halachic perspective. Also, your answer does not mention anything about the philosophy of tseniut - how men and women should act in relation to each other.  ...  ...  Back to the article that quotes all the halakhic literature: At the very least, could you please tell us how it is that you are learning/understanding these mekorot that you relegate them into being quasi-halakhic? (Whatever quasi-halakhic even means...)

Comment: @AdamMosheh - Two main reasons are given in the article for permitting listening to kol isha in general. The first is derived from a little known sefer called Divrei Chefetz, which was cited by the Sdei Chemed. The Divrei Chefetz said that, if the person does not listen to the song for enjoyment, it is muttar to hear a woman sing zemiros, dirges, or lullabies *to put children to sleep*, because these kinds of songs are not romantic. The Sdei Chemed defended the reasoning behind this opinion as sound, but nevertheless disagreed with it and stated that it ought not to be followed….

Comment: ...The Sridei Eish held that the combination of the following factors should permit youth groups where mixed singing is done: (1.) No single voice is prominent, (2.) the leniency of the Divrei Chefetz (which he found cited in the Sdei Chemed), and  (3.) the desperate need for European youth groups for kiruv. Even looking at the Divrei Chefetz by itself, it is talking about hearing non-romantic kol isha without any intent to enjoy it. Somehow, the article morphed this into listening "specifically for the sake of sexual pleasure" or listening to explicitly "lewd songs" and "erotic content."….

Comment: @AdamMosheh The second basis is that there is a machlokes about whether kol isha is a general issur, or whether it is also assur to recite Shema within earshot of a woman singing. Somehow, the latter opinion morphed into "it is ONLY assur to hear a woman singing during Shema, but in general it is fine." These are examples of why these opinions are "outside of mainstream p'sak," as I said.

Comment: @TorasEMES613 - Okay, but due to our many sins in this *t'kufah*, even those who are *karov* are so *rachok*.  Could one take this as a valid reason to rule leniently all the time based on *kiruv*?  To do kiruv k'rovim as well as kiruv r'chokim?

Comment: @TorasEMES613 - Why do you think that these opinions are "outside of mainstream p'sak"?  If that is really the case, then it seems like lot of rabbis are "outside of mainstream p'sak."

Comment: @AdamMosheh, (1.) There may be cases when we choose a lenient p'sak, if reasonable and well supported, rather than push someone away from observance altogether (see Taz, YD 334). (2.) Distorting sources to arrive at a predetermined, desired p'sak - that's what's outside of the mainstream about it. That approach undermines the integrity of the halachic process.

Comment: @TorasEMES613 - So how do you explain the lenient *minhagim* that were practiced way before this essay was published?  And wasn't the *Aruch Hashulchan* famous for often trying to justify existing customs that seem to contradict *halacha* instead of saying that they are all nonsensical?

Comment: "listening 'specifically for the sake of sexual pleasure' or listening to explicitly 'lewd songs' and 'erotic conten'" is forbidden whether it is a man, woman or machine singing.