# Are (opaque) stockings under a skirt considered enough to cover ervah?

Tags: halacha, minhag, women, clothing, tznius-modesty

This is a question about skirt lengths. From [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16462/1516) answer:

> The halacha is that "tefach b'isha ervah" - a tefach (about 3.5
>   inches) uncovered on certain parts of a woman's body is ervah -
>   nakedness. (B'rachos (24a) in the name of Rabbi Yitzchak). The arm
>   must be covered at least to the elbow and the leg must be covered at
>   least to the knee.
>
> [...]
>
> Rabbi Getsel Ellinson (Woman and the Mitzvot: Volume 2) - Pg. 186,
>   note 37, writes that it is probably okay to pray as long as there's
>   less than a tefach uncovered above the elbows and knee. However, it is
>   certainly absolutely forbidden to pray in the presence of a woman
>   whose skirt does not cover past the knees when she is sitting down,
>   because the skirt will not cover ervah.

My question is as follows: if opaque stockings (tights) are worn under a skirt, may the skirt then be any length? Would a skirt that hits more than a tefach above the knee be acceptable in this case (presuming that the skirt falls within the bounds of *aidelkeit* and concern for the local standards)?

Comment: You're going to get very different answers based on hashkafa here.

Comment: Don't the last two sentences of the block quotation contradict one another? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @msh210 Yes, except possibly in light of the stockings issue. For example, a skirt could be a tefach above the knee as long as the upper legs are covered (i.e. by stockings) when she is sitting down...maybe? But good point.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman yes, I imagine so. I guess I'm most interested in a strictly halachic answer. Obviously people have strong opinions about how far it is necessary to go beyond that, and no choice of dress will please everybody.

Comment: Is the Gemara saying that they must be covered, or that prayer may not be recited on front of them?

Comment: Hopefully I'll be able to gather the sources and turn this into an answer, because there are very few answers here that actually cover the nuts and bolts of tznius from a halachic perspective. Opaque stockings are not considered enough to cover the shok--whatever that means--because "covering" halachically means obscuring both shape and color, and the shok must be halachically covered. Opaque stockings obscure color but not shape. A more interesting question would be whether seamed stockings would be enough; Satmar interestingly wear them because the seam distorts the shape of the leg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I suppose you ask how that compares to just wearing pants altogether.

IIUC Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (and I haven't seen this inside) felt that in addition to "thigh", the "split of the legs" should also be covered, therefore pants were inadequate. So ask me how far down a skirt has to go to cover "the split of the legs"... I don't know.

The other issue would be if something is covered, but the clothing is too tight. Not in the spirit of *tzniut*, but hard to argue from a traditional definition of *ervah* per se.

Comment: I'd very much like to see that RMF inside if you can track it down

Answer (score 5):

Reb Shlomo Zalman Orbach zt"l writes in [Minchas Shlomo 103:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47990&st=&pgnum=33) that exposing the stockings is Pritzus and is considered Gilui, since clothing that is usually covered is akin to exposing the flesh. He bases this on the Bach and Shach in Yoreh Deia 340:22 on the Halacha of when a woman rips her clothing for *kriah* that she turns it around. They write that this is although she doesn't rip everything.

Comment: Wouldn't this just depend if the stockings are a clothing that is usually covered or not in that place? The question was asking about reasons that were not location dependent.

Answer (score 1):

There is still a problem of hirur(improper thoughts) see [Igros Moshe EH 4:100:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=168) where he mentions this issue.

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this type of response was excluded by the OP.

Comment: @msh210 thats what the tshuvah says its not a long tshuvah.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am not sure how my answer did not answer the question.

Comment: @sam "(presuming that the skirt falls within the bounds of aidelkeit and concern for the local standards)" and from comments: " I guess I'm most interested in a strictly halachic answer. Obviously people have strong opinions about how far it is necessary to go beyond that, and no choice of dress will please everybody."

Comment: @DoubleAA but look at the first part of the question,its two questions which don't mix.

Comment: unless the second part is coming to explain the first part. (Is the second part חולק or בא לפרש)

Comment: @DoubleAA I dk I thought my answer might help ,but if not,not.