# Length of skirt

Tags: tznius-modesty, shiurim-measurements

If I understand correctly there are two reasons that women wear skirts:

1. To cover the shok
2. To solve the issue of pisuk raglayim

To solve the "shok" concern, I understand that the skirt should reach down to the knees (or further).

How long would the skirt have to be in order to solve just the pisuk raglayim issue?

Comment: Please give a the source of your understanding.

Comment: seemingly even a mini skirt would help for pisuk raglayim, why wouldnt it?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40746/5514

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14281/5514

Comment: @mefaresh seemingly just keeping your legs together solves it too. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Also related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50603/759

Comment: possible duplicate http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27139/759

Comment: Where in halacha to we find the issue of pisuk reglayim?

Comment: @sam  Pesachim 3a Bottom of the amud

Comment: That has nothing to do with skirts?it was more of a rhetorical q

Comment: No, that gemara mentions the issue of *MENTIONING* pisuk raglayim.