# Does one need to kasher a pot that is kosher in all aspects except that kosher meat that is not glatt was cooked in it?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, meat, kashering-kosherization

If one does eat strictly glatt kosher and cooks non-glatt kosher meat in a pot. Later on, a different dish with glatt kosher meat is made. Would someone that adheres to glatt kosher standards require the pot to be kashered in between to continue to uphold glatt kosher standards.

Essentially if non-glatt kosher meat is cooked in a pot, and then glatt kosher meat is cooked in it without kashering in between, would the glatt kosher meat dish be considered non-glatt kosher?

Comment: "glatt kosher standards" is not a well defined term nowadays. Different standards may have different positions on your question.

Answer (score 5):

According to Rav Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe YD 4:6) it seems that using such utensils would be permissible without any kashering . He bases his opnion off the Rama in YD 64:9 which discusses a case where a community allowed a certain type of fat which others considered assur yet the keilim were considered fine for all.

Rav Eliyashiv also holds that all the keilim are permitted to use.
Text of Igros Moshe:

[image]

Text of Rav Eliyashiv psak:

[image]

See my answer here regarding chalev yisrael utensils:

[What is the justification for not requiring "chalav Yisrael" cooking equipment for those who don't hold by R' Moshe's leniency?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73276/what-is-the-justification-for-not-requiring-chalav-yisrael-cooking-equipment-f/98334?r=SearchResults#98334)

Comment: Different position https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114897/759

Answer (score 3):

You really are asking if *blyiot* (absorbed particles that get reabsorbed in food subsequently cooked in the same pots) of non-*glatt* kosher meat are an issue for those eating *glatt*. The answer according to the below authorities is no.

R Yitzchok Yaakov Fuchs (in his book [Hakashrut](https://www.eichlers.com/hakashrut-rav-yitzchok-yaakov-fuchs-hardcover.html), p. 317) writes

> One who is invited to eat in a place where they are not meticulous
> about eating only *glatt* kosher meat may eat there foods that do not
> contain meat although they were cooked in pots that are intended for
> cooking meat in them.

In other words, they are not concerned that non-glatt meat absorbed in a pot will turn *glatt* meat cooked later on in the same pots into non-*glatt*. As such you do not need to kasher the pot.

R Fuchs quotes R Yosef Shalom Eliashiv (brought in Responsa Yashiv Moshe [Turetsky] p. 101) and Chazon Ovadia 1:30.

Comment: "really asking" I think that's a poor way to frame it. There's no question that this is technically wrong and non-glatt particles are in the pot and come out no different from pig. The question is just once we're dealing with pots can we combine other leniencies about how pots transfer flavor to allow relying on the non-glatt opinions that wouldn't have been relied on on their own. For many people that combination of leniencies is sufficient.