# Should one kasher keilim used with Hebrew National?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat, kashering-kosherization, keilim

Do Keilim need to be Kashered after being used for Hebrew National hotdogs?

Comment: Essentially this is your question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117125/does-one-need-to-kasher-a-pot-that-is-kosher-in-all-aspects-except-that-kosher-m?r=SearchResults

Comment: @sam aren't hebrew national hot dogs not kosher at all?

Comment: Under triangle k,non glatt