# Do those who keep Cholov Yisroel eat products marked "K-DE"?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, hechsher-certification, dairy, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

[Some hechshers](http://www.cor.ca/view/183/what_does_dairy_equipment_mean.html) have the designation "DE" for "Dairy Equipment." Do those who keep Cholov Yisroel eat food with this designation? (I am mostly talking about the minority [who consider [American] cholov stam to be treyf](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73274/who-holds-that-cholov-yisroel-is-not-a-chumra). I am guessing there would be no problem with this for others, particularly those who eat K-DE after a meat meal without waiting.)

Comment: from my local C"Y source: "Some people are makpid on keilim, some people are not."

Comment: If it's really Treif then it would be like it says "Treif Equipment" which people generally don't eat.

Comment: I know that some of the local Chabadniks will eat Oreos, which are DE (although the OU doesn't distinguish between milchigs and DE in their nomenclature)

Comment: Are you asking whether they eat stuff made on dairy equipment? Then this seems like a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73276. Or are you asking whether DE stuff is made on dairy equipment? Then you shouldn't include the stuff about _chalav Yisrael_ in the question: it just confuses the issue. Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Are you sure that Oreos are DE? I have heard from a fairly reliable source that Oreos are completely 100% parve (i.e. can be put on a hamburger if you want)

Comment: @Daniel I'd argue that if you want to put oreos on a hamburger you're llike a shoteh and pattur anyways... :D

Comment: @Daniel They are definitely labeled "OUD" these days (because, I am told, the OU retired the OU-DE designation.) I'd be very interested to hear proof that they can be used as a hamburger topping

Comment: @SAH I don't have any proof beyond what I've heard and I certainly wouldn't wager away my life's savings on it. I don't know the reason why they decided to keep the label saying OU-D instead of a plain OU.

Comment: @Daniel It _could_ be (again, I'm assuming that what you said is true) that Oreos wants to reserve the right to change ingredients without changing their label. So to make it easier to switch to a milk-based ingredient on need, they keep the OU-D.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt No True Scotsman and all, but most normative Lubavitchers are also makpid on Pas Palter.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I can't speak for Lubavitch as a whole, only those Lubavitchers I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rama writes (in [Yoreh Deah 115:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.115.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> חָלָב שֶׁל עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים אוֹסְרִים כֵּלִים שֶׁנִּתְבַּשְּׁלוּ בָּהֶם כִּשְׁאָר אִסּוּר, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ רַק סָפֵק שֶׁמָּא עֵרֵב בָּהּ דָּבָר טָמֵא.
>
> Milk of a non-Jew makes vessels non-kosher when they are cooked in them, just as any prohibited food, even though this is only an uncertainty whether he has mixed in something non-kosher.

According to those who says that modern Chalav Stam is **Treif**, there's (presumably) no difference between the olden-day Chalav Akum and modern day.

Comment: Fantastic answer, you got it

Answer (score 0):

It seems from [this](http://www.keterhatorah.com/chalav-yisroel-vs-chalav-akum-vs-chalav-stam-ii/) page that most people who keep cholov yisroel are not makpid about keilim:

> Many who observe the halacha in this manner, are nevertheless lenient
>   with the blias of chalav stam. This was the opinion of Rav Yaakov
>   Kamanetsky and many other American gadolim who, though they only
>   consumed only chalav Yisroel, were not strict about food cooking in
>   pots previously used for non-chalav Yisroel dairy.

However, I can vouch that Chabad is indeed strict on this issue, and thus does not permit products marked K-DE. I would imagine that other Chasidic groups, in particular, would also be stringent on this, but I don't know which ones.

Comment: can you provide the link to such an announcement?

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv Here's where I saw it (cant speak to "incidents of 1983"): http://acriweb.org/docs/ACRIKashrusRecommendations.pdf

Comment: It could be that Rav Yaakov  Kamanetsky followed Igros Moshe, that one should be Machmir, but that it's Muttar MeIkar HaDin.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Are you saying that Igros Moshe says one "*should* be machmir" but that being meikel is nonetheless allowed?

Comment: @SAH MeIkkar HaDin he said that it was Muttar. When you should be Machmir (or Meikil) or whether the Kullah applies nowadays is another question.